# How to configure project to auto reload browser in angular, spring-boot, maven project

Tags: java, angular, maven, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

The project uses Maven, Spring Boot, Angular, Visual Studio Code editor.

How can I configure the project to reload the browser when angular files change?

[spring-boot with angular app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single)

With this dependency in pom.xml, the browser reloads when java files change.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what is wrong with doing `ng serve --watch`?

Comment: the app is run with `$ mvn spring-boot:run` at http://localhost:8080

Comment: How about setting `"start": "ng serve --watch"` in `package.json`?

Comment: How about using live reload https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload
It can be used as chrome plugin or in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client-Server Integration

Server and client projects are on ports 8080 and 4200 respectively.

The client project’s server will be the "front end" (localhost:4200) and all requests will be served by this server except URLs with the pattern "/".

The client server at 4200 will proxy any "/" requests to the "backend" server (localhost: 8080).

To configure this setup, create a file "proxy.conf.json" with the following contents.

```
{
  "/" :{
    "target" : "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure" : false
  }
}
```

Modify the “start” script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Start the "frontend"

```
npm start
```

Start the "backend"

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```